# Why do I get 'KeyError: 0' when using Line Intersection tool?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis, intersection

I'm using Quantum GIS version `1.8.0-Lisboa` and trying to create intersection point using Intersection tool. (Vector -> Analysis tools -> Line Intersections )

But when I do that for my shapefile, It pops up the following error in the dialog box:

```
An error has occured while executing Python code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools/doIntersectLines.py", line 96, in accept
    self.compute(line1, line2, field1, field2, outPath, self.progressBar)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools/doIntersectLines.py", line 174, in compute
    outFeat.addAttribute(0, atMap1[index1])
KeyError: 0

Python version:
2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:27:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3]


QGIS version:
1.8.0-Lisboa Lisboa, exported

Python path: ['/usr/share/qgis/python', '/home/sibi/.qgis//python', '/home/sibi/.qgis//python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/identi-0.1.3-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyipmsg-0.0.1.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rope-0.9.4-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ropemode-0.2-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ropemacs-0.7-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools']
```

Is it some bug in the Quantum GIS program or I'm missing something here?

Comment: Have you checked if all input geometries are valid? Can you share the data so we can try?

Comment: @underdark It's not working for me, for even the simplest of shapefiles I manually created.

Comment: Sample shapefile which didn't work for me, can be downloaded from [here](http://hub.qgis.org/attachments/5274/Shapefile.tar)

Comment: @underdark It is confirmed as a [bug](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/7021) just now. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Ok, that answers the question. Please post the link to the bug report in the answers section or close the question yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with Quantum GIS when working within the same layer.

I have filed a [bug report](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/7021). Thanks.

Update: Got fixed in their current master branch.